# Android No longer want com.test.testservice (pid:5232) hidden #16

Tags: android

I wrote an **android** app (TestApp pid:5231) and there is an independent service named "**testservice**"(pid:5232) in it. Now, I got an odd thing... while I run my app for long time, greater than 30 minutes on my phone, the "testservice" will be killed by system. In the log, I saw below key: "**No longer want com.xxx.xxx**".

Googled that key, and someone said this scenario is caused by low memory, which is the AM mechanism. From my log files, I haven't seen any low memory notice...TT "**No longer want...**"
is a normal scenario or a memory leak issue, Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

From what i know, a service can be killed anytime by the Android OS depending on its policies. Even i have had my long running processes killed without any warning. Low memory issues are hardly the reason as modern smartphones seem to have a lot of memory. The only trick that has worked for me is a **Foreground Service**. According to Android Documentation, foreground services have higher priority to background services. Hence you might want to shift to Foreground service to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Royston, your mentioned way is ok.

Comment: Do accept the answer so that it helps other people who come searching for this same problem :)

Comment: Even if I define a process of highest priority, what are the chances of this happening?